# How to consolidate all characters under one main player to perform same action in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game in `SpriteKit`. The game will include 5 players and instead of coding `SKAction`s five times for every player, I want to consolidate all characters into one and code one time for each `SKAction`, but the code below doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

```
import SpriteKit

var player1 = SKSpriteNode()
var player2 = SKSpriteNode()
var player3 = SKSpriteNode()
var player4 = SKSpriteNode()
var player5 = SKSpriteNode()

var mainPlayer = SKSpriteNode()

// in view did load 

player1 = mainPlayer
player2 = mainPlayer
player3 = mainPlayer
player4 = mainPlayer
player5 = mainPlayer

//in touches began

let rightMoveAction = SKAction.moveByX(50, y: 0, duration: 0.1)

mainPlayer.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rightMoveAction))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your motivation is to make the code shorter and because `mainPlayer` is probably a complex node that you don't want to replicate the code 5 times. You don't show where you add the nodes to the scene, but the way you currently have it will crash when you try to add `player2` because it is already added. It looks like you are trying to simply make 5 of the *same* character that can perform the same action.

Here is a general strategy I would use to try to accomplish what you're after. Since your `mainPlayer` node is probably some complex character that you will be reusing (possibly even in other scenes), then you might consider making it into its own class (and put the code in a separate `.swift` file). You can then add the functions it will use to move and perform other `SKAction`s

For example:

```
import SpriteKit

class Character : SKSpriteNode {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

    //setup your node here
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true//you need this to detect touches

    //log so you know it was created - take this out at some point
    print("character created")
}

//create an example action that will move the node to the right by 50
func moveRight() {
    print("moving right")
    self.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(50, y: 0, duration: 0.1))
}

//you can also override the touch functions so you'll know when the node was touched
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("charater touched")
}
}
```

Then in your scene, when you want to create and use a new character, you can do this:

```
//create the character
let newPlayer = Character.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 50))

//position the character where you want
newPlayer.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)

//add the character to the scene
self.addChild(newPlayer)

/move the character to the right
newPlayer.moveRight()
```

Making things more "modular" like this is great for re-usability of code. Now you can reuse the `Character` class whenever and wherever you need. Even in an entirely different game.

In terms of making all characters run the same action with one function call, I don't know of anything that would allow this. Although you could write your own function for it by perhaps placing all of the character nodes into an array and passing the array as an argument to a custom function, but personally I would just call the `moveRight` function on each of the nodes after you instantiated them.